# Cant center dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown below ive creaeted, but im having troulbe centering the the menu. Ive tried to put `<center>` tags around it and also set the ul to `margin auto 0` but its not working. Is there anything im missing?

```
<style type="text/css">
ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover {
background: #3b3b3b;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a { background: #3b3b3b; }
li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #1e7c9a;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>


<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Logo Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog Design</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Projects</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">This is a project</a></li>
<li><a href="#">So is this</a></li>
<li><a href="#">and this</a></li>
<li><a href="#">don't forget this too</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Quote</a></li>
<li><a href="#">General Enquiry</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I went ahead and put it on jsfiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kXCz8/)

Comment: So you want all 4 buttons centered? Or ?

Comment: I use center and put inline-block in the ul...and is it´s working http://jsfiddle.net/kXCz8/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you actually want to center the list items rather than just the menu.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/kXCz8/8/)

Revised CSS

```
ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center; /* added this */
    font-size:0; /* whitespace adjustment */
}
ul li {
    font-size:1rem; /* font-size reset */
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    /* float: left; removed this */
    display: inline-block;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover {
background: #3b3b3b;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a { background: #3b3b3b; }
li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #1e7c9a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the whole menu centered? If so, it helps to stick that all within something, like a `table` or `div`

so I added the following to your code:

css

```
    #navbar {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

html

```
<div id="navbar">
all your ul/li's
</div>
```

all together

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
    li ul {
        display: none;
    }
    ul li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
        padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
        background: #1e7c9a;
        margin-left: 1px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    ul li a:hover {
    background: #3b3b3b;
    }
    li:hover ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }
    li:hover li {
        float: none;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    li:hover a { background: #3b3b3b; }
    li:hover li a:hover {
        background: #1e7c9a;
    }

    #navbar {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="navbar">
    <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Logo Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog Design</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">This is a project</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">So is this</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">and this</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">don't forget this too</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quote</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">General Enquiry</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle that demo's what I think you're after: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kXCz8/2/)

Basically, I changed your parent `<li>` to `display: inline-block` and removed the `float: left` property. To center those parent nav items, I applied `text-align: center` to the parent `<ul>`. Then I changed the nested dropdowns `ul ul` to be `text-align: left` and then set those `<li>`'s to `display: block`.

**Final CSS (changed some selectors to target differently):**

```
ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center; /* added this */
}
ul > li {
    display: inline-block; /* changed from display: block */
    position: relative;
    /*float: left;*/
}
ul ul { text-align: left; } /* added this */
li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul ul li { display: block; } /* added this */
ul li a:hover {
background: #3b3b3b;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a { background: #3b3b3b; }
li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #1e7c9a;
}
```